# Netflix Proxy - Geolocation

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, proxy

If I am implementing something such as [BetterNet](https://www.betternet.co/), and using something such as [Refer Control](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/referer-control/hnkcfpcejkafcihlgbojoidoihckciin?hl=en), how does their Geo-Location get the correct location?

I have performed several tests, such as DNSLeakTest and ensuring my DNS servers match that of the location I am attempting to use (matching the location of the VPN service) with no issues.

If I use Tor (as a simple test), my data is encrypted (encapsulated/obfuscated) I am redirected to the location; but I'd need to set bridge exit nodes to **always** be a specific location.  Therefore, I surmise it has something to do with Netflix being able to see my original IP Address through the packets sent via my NIC/Browser before the VPN - I.E as though the original packages being sent to the VPN service being inspected and used to locate me.

Can someone give me the technical explanation of how Netflix is capable of performing this?

Comment: maybe they ID your computer somehow

Comment: @jstola You can re-create this on almost any device. I think it comes back to your originating public IP being stored within the original packet, and this being inspected.

Comment: from what I've seen using Netflix via many proxies, they just blacklist IPs of things.  For example I set up several hosted servers and ran a proxy on it, which worked great for several weeks until they got blocked.  From that point on even new virtual servers got blocked, so I think NetFlix is just going around adding IP ranges of known hosting sites.   I would expect TOR exit nodes to be blocked as well.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into this a couple of months ago.  As far as I could tell, Netflix currently leverages [WebRTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC) in order to prevent circumvention of its localization policy.  This is much more simple and robust than maintaining lists of IP addresses of VPN providers.

Roughly, browsers which support WebRTC can access and broadcast information about the local network configuration in order to enable Web applications to do [NAT traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal). This means that, in order to support end-to-end secure calls, the browser would divulge information about the local network, including whether your computer or device is behind a firewall or connected to a VPN.

If you disable WebRTC support in your browser, Netflix would complain about your browser and refuse to work.

This is a very neat technical solution.  For instance, not so long ago, German Law made the owner of an internet connection legally responsible for all its internet traffic.  As a result, public, or semi-public, WiFi connection providers (like Hotels and Resorts) would often turn to VPNs in order to avoid lawsuits resulting from their guests internet traffic.  If Netflix used a blacklist of VPN providers, its users would rightfully complain.  Now, using WebRTC, Netflix users can take advantage of any internet connection and, in particular, VPN users don't need to disable their VPN in order to watch Netflix.  Everything works transparently.